# gvimでOmniSharpを使おうとすると"'omnifunc' は設定されていません"と出る

Tags: c#, windows, vim

タイトルのとおりですが、直接設定したあとも補完がされません。
UnityとVisualStudio2008でプロジェクトを作成して試しましたが、両方とも同じ症状です。
どうしたら直るのかご教授ください。
質問の内容が足りない場合、ご指摘ください。
至らない点あると思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

[image: not set omnifunc]

### 環境

- windows7
- kaoriya-gvim 32bit
- python 2.7.9 32bit
- Unity 4.5.5p5

### vimrc(抜粋)

OmniSharp

```
NeoBundleLazy 'nosami/Omnisharp', {
\   'autoload': {'filetypes': ['cs']},
\   'build': {
\     'windows': 'MSBuild.exe server/OmniSharp.sln /p:Platform="Any CPU"',
\     'mac': 'xbuild server/OmniSharp.sln',
\     'unix': 'xbuild server/OmniSharp.sln',
\   }
\ }
```

neocomplete

```
let g:acp_enableAtStartup = 0
let g:neocomplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:neocomplete#enable_smart_case = 1
let g:neocomplete#sources#syntax#min_keyword_length = 3
let g:neocomplete#lock_buffer_name_pattern = '\*ku\*'
let g:neocomplete#sources#dictionary#dictionaries = {
    \ 'default' : '',
    \ 'vimshell' : $HOME.'/.vimshell_hist',
    \ 'scheme' : $HOME.'/.gosh_completions'
    \ }
if !exists('g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns')
    let g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplete#keyword_patterns['default'] = '\h\w*'

autocmd FileType cs setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete
if !exists('g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns')
  let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns = {}
endif
let g:neocomplete#sources#omni#input_patterns.cs = '[^.]\.\%(\u\{2,}\)\?'
```

vim上で`:set omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete`とすると下の画像のようになります。

[image: set omnifunc error]

Comment: Unityは全く関係ないのではありませんか？少なくともタイトルの最初に出す意味はないと思います。あるいは、`using UnityEngine;`している時だけ補完ができなくなるのでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。thincaさんの回答を見るに、Unity固有の問題の可能性もあるようですね。Unityのプロジェクトだけ補完ができないのか、他のプロジェクトでも補完ができないのか、本文に明記してあると回答の参考になると思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
VisualStudio2008でプロジェクトを作成して試してみましたが、同じ症状が出ましたので、Unityは関係ありませんでした。
タイトルを修正しておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在 omnisharp.vim は `omnifunc` をデフォルトで設定してくれません。(昔は設定されていたのですが、なぜか削除されてしまったようです)

`omnifunc` を自動で設定するようにするには、`~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/cs.vim` と言うファイルを作り、以下のように書きます。

```
setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete
```

> 直接設定したあとも補完がされません。

Omnisharp を利用するにはサーバを起動する必要があります。
デフォルトだと C# ファイルを開いた際に自動で起動するはずですが、Unity だとソリューションファイルが複数あるため、もしかしたらうまく起動してないかもしれません。

```
:OmniSharpStartServerSolution YourProject.sln
```

このコマンドを実行してみてください。(`YourProject.sln` はもちろんあなたのプロジェクトにあるファイルの名前に置き換えてください)

追記:

サーバーは立ち上がっているようですね。権限が足りていないのかもしれません。管理者権限のコマンドプロンプトを起動して、以下のようなコマンドを実行してみてください。

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:2000/ user=thinca
```

`user=` の部分には、あなたのマシンのログイン時に使っているユーザー名を指定してください。2000 は Omnisharp がデフォルトで使用するポート番号です。変更したい場合は適時変えてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
  
> 現在 omnisharp.vim は omnifunc をデフォルトで設定してくれません。(昔は設定されていたのですが、なぜか削除されてしまったようです)  
  
     setlocal omnifunc=OmniSharp#Complete  
  
上記をすることでomnifuncはデフォルトで設定されるようになりました。  
ただ、  
  
     :OmniSharpStartServerSolution YourProject.sln  
  
をしても2枚目の画像と同じようになってしまいます。  
gvimで.csファイルを開いたときにcmdアイコンのOmniSharpが立ち上がるのですが、一度それを終了させgvim上から上記のコマンドを入力しました。

Comment: コメントがきたなくなってしまいました。すみません。

Comment: 最初コメントで返事したのですが、コメントだとうまくフォーマットできなかったので回答の本文に追記をしました。

Comment: 上記のnetshのuser名をログイン時に使っている名前にしたのですが、変わりありませんでした。user名を環境変数のUSERNAMEがSYSTEMだったので、そのようにしたところ"オムニ補完検索中"と出るようになったのですが、"パターンは見つかりませんでした"と2枚めの画像のようになりました

Comment: 補完を開始しようとした際にサーバに何かログは出ていないでしょうか?

サーバへ正しく接続できていれば、何かしらログが出ていると思います。出ていない場合は通信周りがおかしい可能性が高いです。

Comment: OmniSharpサーバのほうは<C-x><C-o>を押しても、00005469 Solution has finished loadingのあとに何か表示されたりはしませんでした。

Comment: とりあえず、タイトルの質問に関して解決しましたので、締めたいと思います。thincaさんご回答ありがとうございました。